# Using sed to replace commas with dot without touching dates

Tags: sed

I need to replace commas (`,`) with dots (`.`) for the field containing numbers. My solution also replaces the dots in the date, which I do not want.

My starting point:

`2020.01.02;2020-01-02;1.321;0.321;2.243;0.032`

What I want:

`2020.01.02;2020-01-02;1,321;0,321;2,243;0,032`

This is what I managed to do, but it also changes the dot in the date to `,`:

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)/\1,\2/g' <file>
2020,01,02;2020-01-02;1,321;0,321;2,243;0,032
    |  |
    `--`--dont want to replace these
```

I tried using `;` in the expression to narrow, but this gets me into problems of pattern matching:

```
         |                      | |     |
$ sed 's/;\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\);/;\1,\2;/g' eg
2020.01.02;2020-01-02;1,321;0.321;2,243;0.032
                             |           |
                             ` not replaced
```

Only every other `.` is replaced.

Or

```
                             |      |
sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\);/\1,\2;/g' eg
2020.01,02;2020-01-02;1,321;0,321;2,243;0.032
       |
       ` do not replace this
```

Any hints or tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Based on your shown samples only, in case you are ok with `awk`, you could try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=";"
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/){
      sub(/\./,",",$i)
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

OR in case you are looking single digit followed by `.` followed by 3 digits then you can try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=";"
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^[0-9]\.[0-9]{3}$/){
      sub(/\./,",",$i)
    }
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks! So it's not feasible to use sed at this?

Comment: @andand, yes we could do that but as hek2mgl sir also mentioned IMHO it would be better to use in `awk` because it has more capability than `sed`, experts also advise to use `awk` for complex tasks too, cheers.

Comment: Thank you RavinderSingh13, for giving me valuable input. I will have to test the different solutions and see which one works best (and the one that I understand best).

Answer (score 4):

Yet another `sed` solution (tested with `GNU sed`, syntax might differ for other implementations)

This forms a loop by using a label `a` for the substitute command. As long as there's a match found, `ta` will jump to the label `a`. The match condition is presence of `.` character between exactly two sequences of digits. I have used `+` quantifier, which can be changed to `*` if needed.

```sh
sed -E ':a s/(;[0-9]+)\.([0-9]+(;|$))/\1,\2/; ta'
```

If the first column can also match, use this:

```sh
sed -E ':a s/((^|;)[0-9]+)\.([0-9]+(;|$))/\1,\3/; ta'
```

This is easier to do with lookarounds:

```sh
perl -pe 's/(^|;)\d+\K\.(?=\d+(;|$))/,/g'
```

See my tutorial [Emulating regexp lookarounds in GNU sed](https://learnbyexample.github.io/sed-lookarounds/) for more such workarounds in `GNU sed` when lookarounds are needed.

Comment: This perl solution is cool, may be this could also be added in your Magic commands Online git book/documentation :)

Comment: Perl regexp has too many features. I have a [basic tutorial here](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/perl_the_swiss_knife.md#lookarounds) but I'd suggest https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut for a better and more complete resource

Comment: Thank you Sundeep, for giving me valuable input. I will have to test the different solutions and see which one works best (and the one that I understand best).

Comment: branching, nice idea!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use awk as it is simpler to read / write:

```
awk -F\; 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){sub(/\./,",",$i)}}1'
```

in multiline form:

```
awk -F\; '
BEGIN{OFS=FS}
{
    # starting with the 3rd field, replace '.' by ','
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
        sub(/\./,",",$i)
    }
}
1 # print the line'
```

Comment: Thanks! So it's not feasible to use sed at this?

Comment: Thank you hek2mgl, for giving me valuable input. I will have to test the different solutions and see which one works best (and the one that I understand best).

Comment: Hey @andand! As others showed now, there are ways to do it with `sed`. I would use `awk` for better readability

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU sed` which supports `\b` (word boundary), how about:

```
sed -E 's/\./,/g; s/\b([0-9]{4}),([0-9]{2}),([0-9]{2})\b/\1.\2.\3/g' file
```

It once replaces all dots with commas, then restores back again within dates. I suppose this is not robust enough and there will be some edge cases which do not work well.

Comment: Thank you tshiono, for giving me valuable input. I will have to test the different solutions and see which one works best (and the one that I understand best).

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved with sed, but it is not as straightforward as you imagine. Even when using GNU sed and exploit the use of word-boundaries, could lead to wrong matches.

Let's imagine that `bre` is the Basic regular expression which matches the fields you are interested in. If your strings looks like:

```
foo;bar;bre;baz;qux
foo;bar;brebaz;qux
foo;bar;bre;bre;baz;qux
```

This would match `bre` in all cases, even if we are not interested in `brebaz`. So you could prepend it with `;` and try to match `;bre`. This would still match `;brebaz`. But if we add it to the end as well (i.e. `;bre;`) it will not match the second `;bre;` in the third example due to the overlap.

The trick is now to do the following actions:

1. double the field separators (`;` → `;;`)
2. sandwich the string between field separators (`string` → `;string;`)
3. do the match on `;bre;`
4. remove the sandwich and un-double the field separators (`;` ← `;;`)

The following regex defines a floating point number:

```
[-+]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

This will match any of the forms `123`, `123.45`, `123.45E+6`. Since we want to replace the <dot>-character into a <comma>-character, we just need to modify it a bit. Furthermore, we know that the first column is not a number, so it always starts with a <semicolumn>-character. The modified regex would look like:

```
(;[-+]?[0-9]+)[.]([0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?;)
```

So performing all the actions above; with converting the above to a proper `sed` expression (escaping all the needed characters), we get:

```
sed -e 's/;/;;/g;s/.*/;&;/;s/\(;[-+]\?[0-9]\+\)[.]\([0-9]*\([eE][-+]\?[0-9]\+\)\?;\)/\1,\2/g;s/;;/;/g;s/;\(.*\);/\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you kvantour, for giving me valuable input. I will have to test the different solutions and see which one works best (and the one that I understand best).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'G;:a;s/([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})\n/\n\1/;ta;s/\.\n/\n,/;ta;s/(.)\n/\n\1/;ta;s/.//' file
```

Append a newline to each line and then parse the line, removing the newline when the line has been parsed.

There are 3 rules to look for:

- a date i.e. `yyyy.mm.dd\n`, replace by `\nyyyy.mm.dd` where y,m and d are integers
- a period i.e. `.\n`, replace by `\n,` this is required action.
- an arbitrary character e.g. `x\n`, replace by `\nx`

Repeat until all rules fails and then remove the newline at the start of the line.